# Getting only Last Object name in a ListView

Tags: android, json

I am `parsing` this **JSON**:

```
{
"technology" : [

{
"title" : "Android",
"images" : [
{
"name" : "Android - I"
},
{
"name" : "Android - II"
},
{
"name" : "Android - III"
}
]
}

]
}
```

I parsed `technology` and `images` JSON Arrays, but whenever i do tap on Android just getting last object name in list view , in this case "Android - III" ?

So may i know What could be the reason.... ?

**TechnologyActivity.java:-**

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
    JSONArray techArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("technology");
        for(int i=0; i<techArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject jObject = techArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Technology tech = new Technology();
            tech.setTitle(jObject.getString("title"));
            Log.d("technology-title:", jObject.getString("title"));

            JSONArray imagesArray = jObject.getJSONArray("images");
              for(int j=0; j<imagesArray.length(); j++)
              {
                JSONObject imagesObject = imagesArray.getJSONObject(j);
                SubTech images = new SubTech();
                images.setName(imagesObject.getString("name"));
                Log.d("technology-name", imagesObject.getString("name"));

                arrayListImages = new ArrayList<SubTech>();
                arrayListImages.add(images);
                }
            tech.setImages(arrayListImages);
            arrayList.add(tech);
        }
```

**SubTechActivity.java:-**

```
public class SubTechActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Technology> arrayList;
    Technology tech;
    SubTechAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<SubTech> arrayListSubTech;
    int currentPosition ;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_technology);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        arrayList = (ArrayList<Technology>) bundle.getSerializable("data");
        currentPosition = bundle.getInt("current");

        tech = arrayList.get(currentPosition);

        arrayListSubTech = tech.getImages();

        ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new SubTechAdapter(SubTechActivity.this, R.layout.adapter_technology, arrayListSubTech);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: post `technologyactivity.java` and why do you need to pass the arraylist when you pass the required item itself

Comment: Does `Technology` class implement parcelable?

Comment: I posted my whole code of TechnologyActivity.java but due to some reasons i have to pass whole arraylist

Comment: yes my both the java classes implements Serializable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are everytime creating a new instance of `arrayListImages = new ArrayList<SubTech>();` inside the for loop, it should be create only once and that too outside the loop

```
    arrayListImages = new ArrayList<SubTech>();

    for(int j=0; j<imagesArray.length(); j++)
        {
            JSONObject imagesObject = imagesArray.getJSONObject(j);
            SubTech images = new SubTech();
            images.setName(imagesObject.getString("name"));
            Log.d("technology-name", imagesObject.getString("name"));

            arrayListImages.add(images);
        }
```

Comment: yeah you were right, i just moved arrayListImages = new ArrayList<SubTech>(); before for loop and done !